# Cell not displaying elements when being reused on a stack that adds a LinkPresentation view

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, uistackview

I had this custom view who worked like a charm before i introduce a LinkView for a Metadata [image: The idea is to show some tweet info as you can see on preview]

After i introduce a LinkView, since it was inside a stackView i had to remove linkView from superview when preparing for reusable (not sure why tried to redraw layout, but seems this not work with LinkView) the problems shows up when scrolling down elements, seems the data get lost at certain point, curious thing is that it only happens with the reusable element that contains the linkView item, is there any reason for this ? How can i fix it ?

[image: Data get lost]

Here is the code i use for the cell

```
final class TimeLineTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 6
    var shadowOffsetWidth = 0
    var shadowOffsetHeight = 3
    var shadowColor: UIColor = .gray
    var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.3
    
    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(stackViewContainer)
        
        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        view.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.layer.masksToBounds = false
        view.layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowOffsetWidth, height: shadowOffsetHeight);
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        view.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var stackViewContainer: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .horizontal
        stack.alignment = .center
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.distribution = .fill
        stack.spacing = 10.0
        stack.addArrangedSubview(profileImage)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(stackViewDataHolder)
        return stack
    }()
    
    lazy var profileImage: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImage()
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }()
    
    lazy var userName: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
    }()
    
    lazy var tweetInfo: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
    }()
    
    lazy var tweetText: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
    }()
    
    lazy var linkView: LPLinkView = {
        let viewer = LPLinkView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 200, height: 20)))
        viewer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return viewer
    }()
    
    lazy var stackViewDataHolder: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.distribution = .fillProportionally
        stack.addArrangedSubview(userName)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(tweetInfo)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(tweetText)
        return stack
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        linkView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    
    func configure(viewModel: ProfileTweetViewModel) {
        tweetInfo.configure(model: viewModel.tweetInfo)
        userName.configure(model: viewModel.name)
        tweetText.configure(model: viewModel.tweet)
        if let metadata = viewModel.linkData {
            linkView = LPLinkView(metadata: metadata)
            stackViewDataHolder.addArrangedSubview(linkView)
            //Tried almost all layoyt options but seems a previous view can't be updated since frame is wrong
        }
        
        if let url = viewModel.profilePic {
            profileImage.downloadImage(from: url)
        }
    }
}

private extension TimeLineTableViewCell {
    struct Metrics {
        static let lateralPadding: CGFloat = 8
    }
    
    func constraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: Metrics.lateralPadding),
            stackViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -Metrics.lateralPadding),
            stackViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: Metrics.lateralPadding),
            stackViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -Metrics.lateralPadding),
            
            profileImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImage.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            profileImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
        ])
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        addSubview(containerView)
        backgroundColor = .clear
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 4),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -4),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
        ])
        
        constraints()
    }
    
    
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to `.fillProportionally` in stackView
since the linkView sometimes renders with 0 height, i just had to use `.fill` property in stackView in order to show it fully